# Google Map API v3, load infoWindow content via setContent using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm loading markers from a database in XML format and breaking it out using a for() loop but I have an addListener event 'click' that contains an AJAX call I'm having trouble with.  I'm trying to populate the content of my infoWindow with the data pulled down in the ajax call.

Here is a copy of my code inside the for() loop:

```
var mkID = mk[i].getAttribute("id");

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
    icon: "/img/icon.png",
    title: "Click to Show"
});

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg' style='color: #FFA46B;' title='Loading...'></i> Loading..."
});

markerArray.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infoWindow, mkID) {
    return function() {
        if(infoWindow) {
            infoWindow.close();
        }
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/map-info-ajax.html?id=' + mkID,
            success: function(data) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data);
            }
        });
    };
})(marker, infoWindow, mkID));
```

I tried changing this:

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg' style='color: #FFA46B;' title='Loading...'></i> Loading..."
});
```

to just this:

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

But the info windows are just coming up blank now when **data** does contain 'xyzzy ya ya ya'.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Regards,
Vince

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  That is effectively what is done in [this example from the documentation for the Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search) when it request the place details.

Comment: Why don't you load the infowindow content along with the markers in the first place?

Comment: @MrUpsidown When I build a website I try to always imagine that at a minimum it will be receiving 1,000,000 hits per day and that they will all be via cell phone.  So I do my best to reduce the amount of PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS and JavaScript parsing time/bandwidth required wherever I can.  Besides, pulling down info window content via AJAX after the fact is very logical and common request among Google Map API developers here.  My only problem is that I just haven't been able to get any of the solutions for accessing the 'data' pulled down via AJAX to work in my code so far.  I need fresh eyes.

Comment: Did you debug? Does the ajax request work? Did you double check the URL? Is anything returned in the success callback? If yes, what does it look like? Help us to help you.

Comment: Just as a side note, I would set the content and *then* open the infowindow, not the inverse.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've changed the way the AJAX call works about 10 times and it always works properly.  I think what I might need to do is stop the AJAX call from executing asynchronously.  I mentioned in my example above that the data does contain content, 'xyzzy ya ya ya'.  I open the infoWindow first so I can display a loading spinner icon and text first.  Once I have the new content I planned on updating the infoWindow with the new data but that doesn't matter because I've tried it both ways.  The problem is really in how to get the data out of the AJAX call and into  a variable I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got this working.  Here is what the code looks like now.

```
var mkID = mk[i].getAttribute("id");

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
    icon: "/img/icon.png",
    title: "Click to Show"
});

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg' style='color: #FFA46B;' title='Loading...'></i> Loading..."
});

markerArray.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infoWindow, mkID) {
    return function() {
        if(infoWindow) {
            infoWindow.close();
        }
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        infoWindowAjax(mkID, function(data) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data);
        });
    };
})(marker, infoWindow, mkID));
```

And the infoWindowAjax() function that it calls.

```
function infoWindowAjax(mkID, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/map-info-ajax.html?id=' + mkID
    })
    .done(callback)
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

I had to move the ajax call to it's own function and use a callback to get the information back to where I could use it once it had run it's course.

PS: I was using jQuery v2.1.1.

PPS: If the data returned is just simple raw text, even UTF-8 content, make sure the PHP template header is set like **header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");**.  One little bug I ran into was that I had mine set incorrectly to **text/xml**.

Comment: Good to see that you got it sorted. You are right, the header part (server side) is important. You might want to define the `dataType` on the ajax request too, although it is supposed to do an *intelligent guess* as the doc says.